# Why is a root system called a "root" system?

Tags: representation-theory, terminology, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

Root systems plays an important role in, among other things, classifying semisimple Lie Algebras. Their name suggest that they have something to do with "roots" of a polynomial. Are they the roots of some polynomial? Where does the name "**root** system" come from?

Comment: roots of a characteristic poly of $t$ in a  torus acting on the lie algebra- see almost exactly 5 minutes on, from approx the 15:00 mark in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x95hJ6F87fw&index=11&list=PL6079A8A50EFA181B of Gross's lecture

Comment: For the corresponding question regarding *weights*, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/q/154933/27465

Answer (score 11):

It comes from the roots of the characteristic polynomial of an endomorphism. If $\mathfrak g$ is a complex semisimple Lie algebra, $\mathfrak h$ is a Cartan subalgebra and $\alpha\in\mathfrak{h}^*$, then $\alpha$ is a root if, for every $H\in\mathfrak h$, $\alpha(H)$ is an eigenvalue of the endomorphism of $\mathfrak g$ defined by $X\mapsto[H,X]$.

Comment: ...except that, usually by fiat, $0$ is not a root.

Comment: @Stephen You are right, of course. I forgot that convention.

Comment: Is there a way to describe that same characteristic polynomial without referencing semisimple Lie algebras? Like, just starting with the axioms of a root system? Or starting with a Dynkin/Euclidean diagram and it's corresponding Cartan/Tits form?

Comment: I've asked my previous comment as a [separate question here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/294263/64073).